I have two different DB version and trying the create the physical folder in windows
I have two different DB versions and am trying to create the physical folder in Windows.
DB -1
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit ProductionPL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
DB -2
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.3.0  Production"
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
the code is below
create or replace and compile java source named "CreateDir_1"

as

  import java.io.*;

public class CreateDir_1 extends Object {

  public static void Create(String dir) {

   File f = new File(dir);

   f.mkdir();

  }

}

/

create or replace procedure create_dir_1 (p in varchar2)

as

language java

name 'CreateDir_1.Create(java.lang.String)';

/
begin

create_dir_1('\\130.78.62.105\RCM_Reports\Test_Dir_0769');

end;

DB-1 the folder was successfully created but in DB-2 the folder was not created. please help me

maybe because of that address 130.78.62.105 was not accessible/not mapped on the server where DB-2 runs? Hard to tell, you need to see the exception, so catch it and paste it here.

java.security.AccessControlException: the Permission (java.io.FilePermission \130.78.62.105\RCM_Reports\SA write) has not been granted to IBAEHIS. The PL/SQL to grant this is dbms_java.grant_permission( 'IBAEHIS', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '\130.78.62.105\RCM_Reports\SA', 'write' )

can you please let me know how to give the grant access

select * from USER_JAVA_POLICY where grantee_name = 'IBAEHIS'
TYPE_NAME - java.io.FilePermission
ACTION - read,write,delete
still facing same issue folder not created
